# Android: Custom Toolbar in Fragments issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

My project is for a quiz and I've made the questions as fragments. I've added a custom toolbar, which has navigation buttons and question# indicator (dots). I encountered two issues:

1.The toolbar swipes with the question /either by gesture or by pressing the next button in it/. I guess, the toolbar is created with the new fragment. I want this toolbar to be static - swiping/clicking next should change only the content and the toolbar should't move.

> I've solved the #1 problem by changing
>
> > pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1,**true**);
> >     to
> >     pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1,**false**);

2.I want to hide/show previous/next buttons on the toolbar on a certain fragment - the first fragment shouldn't have previous button and the last fragment shouldn't have a next button. I've tried to change visibility from the FragmentActivity class (which I've changed to AppCompatActivity), but it gives the error - "Trying to invoke setVisibility on a null object reference"

I've used `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>` in all fragment xml files to include the toolbar.

**toolbar xml**

```
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="previous"
        android:id="@+id/previousQ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:onClick="previousQ"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countQ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="●○○○○"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="next"
        android:id="@+id/nextQ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:onClick="nextQ"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`

**FragmentActivity class**

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

public void nextQ(View view) {
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
}

public void previousQ(View view) {
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1,true);
}
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {
            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            case 2: return FirstFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            case 3: return FirstFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            case 4: return FirstFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you tried to change the button visibility? You can try to add id to you relative layout and then change visibility this way:

```
toolbar2.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutId).findViewById(R.id.nextQ)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I've tried what you said - added ID to the relative layout(toolbar1 ) and (not sure if right here?) added toolbar2.toolbar1.findViewById(R.id.nextQ); in the toolbar buttons methods , but it says "Cannot resolve symbol toolbar1"

Comment: Ahh sorry. I edit my answer. With your id it should be like this: toolbar2.findViewById(R.id.toolbar1).findViewById(R.id.nextQ)